# Select all data in Excel by column name, omitting empty cells

Tags: excel, graph, excel-formula

The goal is to create a series of graphs that will update automatically based on the raw data.

So, I have created a graph manually and want to edit the formula to accomplish the auto update.

The column names will always be the same, so I want to be able to select all data in a column based on the name BUT ignore any cell that is blank (above zero maybe).

The formula excel has given me so far is

```
=SERIES(rawdata!$M$1:$M$6,rawdata!$A$2:$A$37,rawdata!$M$2:$M$37,1)
```

So, something like

```
=SERIES(rawdata![column name],rawdata![column name],rawdata![column name],1)
```

I'm not sure how the skipping blank columns should work either. To expand on this further only one of the columns can potentially contain blank values. So if a cell is blank in that column then that entire row shouldn't be plotted, if that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**    =OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B:$B) - 1)

Try this formula when you define the name for the column of values you would like to have data automatically added from. I know it works when each cell has either a formula or a value. Like a column that is automatically calculated based on values in other columns.

In this formula example the cell **B2** refers to the first point of data in the column. (make sure your references are absolute! ie, use $B$2)

This automatically returns the range of data as it changes when CountA is added:

---

```
 =OFFSET(reference, rows, cols, [height], [width])

 =COUNTA(value1, [value2], ...)
```

---

Hope this helps! It worked for me! :) If you have completely blank cells in the column you might have to make a couple changes though.

-Reverus